# Can I change the color of my lips?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Playing Mass Effect: Andromeda, I have my character customized to be exactly as I want... except one thing. The lips on my character are a godawful shade of bright pink, and do not match at all with my complexion.

I tried to look for a way to change it in the character creator, but I couldn't find it. I've also searched all over for a console command to fix it and came up with the same result.

**So that leads me to this question of how can I change my character's lip color; both during character creation for future reference and after the character has been created?**

Comment: I was sure this was a joke post about the lip syncing issues that I heard about that game.

Comment: @Fredy31 After looking at myself in the mirror, I realized the character models weren't that bad, and that I don't usually move my mouth more than they do. :P

Comment: I'm so glad I'm not the only person who had issues with this. I restarted the game multiple times after chargen and the first cutscene because my Ryder's lip color made her look like a corpse. I think the lip color mask they apply is configured for the preset's original skin tone, so that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

There's not actually a way to change the lip's base color. However, you *can* choose to apply lipstick to your character and modify the color and opacity to get the exact shade you want to make your character as desired.

From [this guide](http://twinfinite.net/2017/03/mass-effect-andromeda-character-creation-guide/2/) that lists all customization options and settings, these are the only lip settings:

> - Mouth – Lip Thickness
> - Lipstick Color

I can't speak for the shape of the lips (I was a bit disappointed with the small window of variance of a lot of the facial features), but the color should be easy enough to get exactly what you want.

Unfortunately, once you've created your character at the beginning of the game, there **is no way to change it** without starting a new game. This has been mentioned on multiple sites, such as [this one](http://m.gamerevolution.com/faq/mass-effect-andromeda/can-you-change-your-appearance-130119):

> BioWare chose not to include a character editor or appearance modifier. What you design at the beginning of the game can't be changed through conventional means.

Comment: +1, but I'm asking also about the non-conventional means that the excerpt mentioned.

Comment: @Anoplexian I believe the "conventional means" refers to the usual ability to edit your character's appearance. From what I was reading, it sounded like this was possible in previous Bioware games, like Dragon Age Inquisition, just not this one.